# logstash's syslog is not consuming logs from rsyslog server

Tags: logstash, rsyslog

I am having above configuration for rsyslog server to output it to logstash,

```
$tail /etc/rsyslog.d/70-output.conf
*.*       @@logstash:5514
```

And in logstash.conf I have configured it as follows,

```
input {
syslog {
type => "syslog"
port => "5514"
}
}

output {
file {
path => "/var/log/logstash/debug.log"
codec => "json"
}
}
```

How can I debug it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) helped me to check whether I receive syslog on logsatsh or not.